# ubuntu linux gmsh gives "sh: 1: python: not found" error

Tags: python, sockets, ubuntu, runtime-error, gmsh

I try to run a Gmsh python script from the command line (or from PyCharm or Spyder)

```
gmsh script.py
```

but I get the following error:

```
sh: 1: python: not found
```

also in the Gmsh console there is this error:

```
Done - 1 error : Abnormal server termination (Socket listening timeout on socket /home/user/.gmshsock2)
```

I did check python3 version which looks fine:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.4
```

What could be the problem?

Can anyone help to solve this ?

Thanks

Oli

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that Python is installed on your system, but that there is no symlink from `python3` to `python`. Therefore `python3` is a valid command and confirms that python is installed, but the command `python` is no available.

As you tagged `ubuntu`, i would suggest you to install the package `python-is-python3` with the following command

```bash
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

This package will create a symlink from `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3`, and therefore `gmsh` can execute the command `python`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the " sh: 1: python: not found " error.

Comment: The second error, visible in the gmsh console, " Abnormal server termination (Socket listening timeout on socket /home/user/.gmshsock2) ", remains however